# Upload to App Store Xcode archive error "Could not merge changes"

Tags: ios, xcode

When I archive my iOS app and press **Upload to App Store** I receive this error:

[image: Screenshot]

Can anyone tell me what this means, or how to fix it?

Comment: Try disabling bitcode in project settings

Comment: I quit Xcode, reopened and now it's working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quit Xcode, reopen and try again.